# How can I change the units of the scale bar from km to mi for a SpatRaster?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, terra

I am trying to create a map in ggplot with a SpatRaster basemap (CRS 26913 - NAD83, UTM ZONE 13N). When I try to use the function annotation_scale to add a scale bar, the distance represented by the scale_bar appears correct in kilometers. However, when I try to change the plot_unit argument to "mi" for miles, the map returned has an inaccurate scale bar in km still. I'm trying to achieve an accurate scale bar in miles.

I have a SpatRaster of NAIP imagery named `img` that I am trying to map using ggplot so I can add in other `sf` objects. I am unable to change the scale bar from km to mi. I have tried three different functions including `annotation_scale` and `ggsn::scalebar` and `terra::sbar`. It's currently in the coordinate reference system NAD 83 UTM ZONE 13N (EPSG: 26913).

```
> class(img) 
[1] "SpatRaster"attr(,"package")
[1] "terra"
```

```
> crs(img)
[1] "PROJCRS["NAD83 / UTM zone 13N",\n    BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",\n        DATUM["North American Datum 1983",\n            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],\n        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID["EPSG",4269]],\n    CONVERSION["UTM zone 13N",\n        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",\n            ID["EPSG",9807]],\n        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID["EPSG",8801]],\n        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-105,\n            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID["EPSG",8802]],\n        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],\n            ID["EPSG",8805]],\n        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],\n            ID["EPSG",8806]],\n        PARAMETER["False northing",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],\n            ID["EPSG",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS["(E)",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],\n        AXIS["(N)",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],\n        AREA["North America - between 108°W and 102°W - onshore and offshore. Canada - Northwest Territories; Nunavut; Saskatchewan. United States (USA) - Colorado; Montana; Nebraska; New Mexico; North Dakota; Oklahoma; South Dakota; Texas; Wyoming."],\n        BBOX[28.98,-108,84,-102]],\n    ID["EPSG",26913]]"
```

Here I tried mapping the SpatRaster with `annotation_scale`.

```
# Map with annotation_scale with default settings (scalebar in km)
sat_1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img) +
    annotation_scale(location = "bl") +
    ggtitle("sat_1")

sat_1
```

[Map with annotation_scale and default arguments (scale bar is accurate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXOMt.png)

```
# Map with annotation_scale with argument "mi"
sat_2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img) +
    annotation_scale(location = "bl", plot_unit = "mi") +
    ggtitle("sat_2")

sat_2
```

[Map with annotation_scale with plot_unit argument of miles (scalebar is wildly off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5V7j.png)

```
# Map with ggsn::scalebar, didn't even work - see Error message below:
sat_3 <- ggplot() +
    geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img) +
    ggsn::scalebar(data = img, dist = 1, location = "bottomleft", transform = FALSE) +
    ggtitle("sat_3")

sat_3

SpatRaster resampled to ncells = 500379
Error: [subset] invalid name(s)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to get an accurate scale bar in miles using a UTM or perhaps another projection?

Comment: please provide some example data by creating it in code like `img <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, crs=... , ext= ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ggsn`. Problem is that `ggsn::scalebar()` needs a `data` object of the same extent that your SpatRaster.

You can hack this by creating a SpatVector from the extent of your SpatRaster (ensuring that both have the same CRS) and then pass it to sf with `sf::st_as_sf()` .

Now just use `dist_unit` param at your convenience:

```r
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)
library(terra)


# Get the data from extent using maptiles
x <- rast(xmin = -103.50, xmax = -103.38, ymin = 29.58, ymax = 29.70) %>%
  project("EPSG: 26913")

img <- maptiles::get_tiles(x, "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  project(pull_crs(x)) %>%
  crop(x)

# This is for checking with terra
# For locating
ext <- as.vector(ext(img))[c(1, 3)]

plotRGB(img, mar = c(3, 0, 0, 0))
sbar(6000, type = "bar", xy = ext - c(0, 1200), label = c("0", "3", "6 km"))

# On miles
sbar(6000 / 0.621371, type = "bar", xy = ext - c(0, 1200 * 2), label = c("0", "3", "6 mi"))
```

[image]

```r
# (Sorry, image seems to be cropped with hop you get the idea)

# With ggsn we need a sf object
v <- ext(img) %>% as.polygons()
crs(v) <- pull_crs(img)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img) +
  ggsn::scalebar(
    data = sf::st_as_sf(v),
    location = "bottomleft",
    dist = 3,
    st.size = 4,
    st.dist = 0.05,
    transform = FALSE,
    dist_unit = "km"
  ) +
  coord_sf() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = ""
  )
```

[image]

```r
# On miles
ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster_rgb(data = img) +
  ggsn::scalebar(
    data = sf::st_as_sf(v),
    location = "bottomleft",
    dist = 3,
    st.size = 4,
    st.dist = 0.05,
    transform = FALSE,
    dist_unit = "mi"
  ) +
  coord_sf() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = ""
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @dieghernan! The ggsn::scalebar worked after using the property boundary (which was already an 'sf' object) in the data argument. I appreciate your help!